# How to get double click event in angular-datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using datatables and angular-datatables.
How do I detect a double click event in the datatable and get the row data?
I found the code below but I need it in angular.

```
$(document).on("dblclick", "#myTable tr", function () {
    //code here
});
```

**html**

```
<table datatable="tblRecipe" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" dt-instance="showCase.dtInstance" class="table table-bordered"></table>
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['datatables'])
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $window, $http, $filter, $timeout, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dtInstance = {};
    vm.Recipes = {};
    vm.delete = deleteRow;
    vm.edit = editRow;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
        url: "/Recipes/GetAllRecipes",
        type: "POST"
    })
    .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
    .withOption('select', true);
    vm.dtColumns = [
                    //...
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable().renderWith(actionsHtml)
        ];
        function actionsHtml(data, type, full, meta) {
            vm.Recipes[data.Id] = data;
            return '<a title="View"  href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showCase.view(showCase.Recipes[' + data.Id + '])">' +
                ' <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + '</a>' + '<a title="Edit"  href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showCase.edit(showCase.Recipes[' + data.Id + '])">' +
                ' <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>' + '</a>' + '<a title="Delete" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showCase.delete(showCase.Recipes[' + data.Id + '])" )"="">' + ' <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>' + '</a>';
        };
        //...
});
});
```

Comment: are you using angularjs 1?

Comment: @Sathiyaraj Yes, angularjs 1.6.6

Comment: can you post the code ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't have angular code for the double click event that's what I'm asking. I'll edit my question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using datatables and angular-datatables. How do I detect a double
>   click event in the datatable and get the row data? I found the code
>   below but I need it in angular.

DataTables *is* jQuery, Angular-DataTables is just directives that make them work in a AngularJS context. Unless you are rendering "the angular way", i.e `datatable="ng"` you will need to `$compile` the table, the rows or each cell in callbacks if you want any directive to work.

Simply use a delegated event handler as you would do with jQuery DataTables, and grab the data through `dtInstance` which among other things hold the API instance :

```
$('#tableId').on('dblclick', 'tbody tr', function() {
  console.log( $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row(this).data() )
})
```

---

Update: **http://plnkr.co/edit/PdrKxxxsDFdNSzgf8c07?p=preview**

Answer (score 0):

We can write a custom directive logic and resolve the issue. can you please refer [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) .

html code

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
<div id="goodDiv" ngdblclick>Click Here</div>
<div id="goodDiv">Don't Click Here</div>
</div>
```

angular code

```
angular.module("myapp", []).
controller("MainController", ["$scope", function($scope){

}]).
directive("ngdblclick", ['$compile', function($compile){
    'use strict'
    return{
        compile : function(elements, attributes){
            return{
                restrict: 'C',
                post : function(scope, element, attribute){
                    var isSingleClick = true;
                    element.bind('click', function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            if(isSingleClick){
                                console.log("It's a single click");
                                return;
                            }
                        }, 500);
                    });

                    element.bind('dblclick', function(){
                        console.log("It's a double click");
                        isSingleClick = false;
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            isSingleClick = true;
                            return;
                        }, 500);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

css style:

```
#goodDiv{
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    background-color : green;
}
```

You can find your element and render the event for specific element(#myTable li)

Comment: 1, Why inject `$compile` to the directive? 2. Why use `setTimeout`? 3. And why not use angularjs' own `ng-dblclick` instead?

Comment: 1. $compile is dynamic rebind the element and get the scope of the value, 2. we need to understand the interval of the next consecutive click event listen 3. we unable to bind ng-double click event in angular element inject.

Comment: 1. You are not using `$compile` at all, `$compile` is implicit in the directive method. 2. You should never use `setTimeout` with angularjs but `$timeout` 3. Your solution will never work with angular datatables since angular not is aware of whatever DOM elements DT is injecting. You just replace a standard directive that will not work without `$compile` with another directive that will not work without `$compile` ...